# DataBase connectivity with sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I connected sqlite it's successful. Even inserted data into table but while trying to fetch and print nothing showing.

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
def db_connect(db_file):
     try:
        conn=sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
     except Error as e:
        print(e)
     return conn

def db_operation(conn,str):
 try:

    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute(str)
    res=c.fetchall()
    for i in res:
        print(i)
except Error as e:
    print(e)
return res


if __name__=='__main__':
    database=r'E:\sqlite\test.db'
    conn=db_connect(database)
    if conn:
       print("enter the query")
       str=input()
       res=db_operation(conn,str)
```

Comment: can you add an example of your query ??

Comment: create table demo values(id integer,name text)

Comment: select * from demo

Comment: try firts in your code to create the table and insert data before the select

Comment: When you inserted data did you finish up with a commit?

Comment: pls , add how you are inserting your data in your code